# Amazon OpenSearch, Create vector index - Failed to fetch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-opensearch

When trying to create a Vector search I get error Failed to fetch. Response is 403.

Access to fetch at 'https://ohd3pf1346ke3z7kau79.eu-central-1.aoss.amazonaws.com/aaa' from origin 'https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Create a vector index in AWS OpenSearch